# XMLStarlet: XML parsing error

Tags: xml, xslt

```
xsltCopyText: text allocation failed
runtime error: element value-of
xsltValueOf: text copy failed
```

Got this error when parsing XML (wikipedia dump, actually) w/ XMLStarlet. I can get page titles and ids, but when it comes to page texts, it fails.

Expression used:

```
xml sel -N xmlns=http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/ -T -t -m "//xmlns:revision" -v "xmlns:text" -n d:\wiki\translated.wiki.xml
```

P.S. I'm doing it on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the content of `translated.wiki.xml`? Just check the first few lines, it may have been corrupted somewhere.

Can you reproduce the problem on a small subset of `translated.wiki.xml`? Wikipedia dumps are **huge** and often crash tools which allocate memory too greedily.

Comment: I validated translated.wiki.xml w/ XMLStarlet, and it's consistent.

Yes, it works correctly on small subset. Must be memory issues. Stupid, stupid me :)

Comment: Okay, problem solved using Xalan (with XSLT generated by XML Starlet).